# Exception on execution PhantomJS + Selenium Webdriver + Python program

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, headless-browser

With all installation prerequisite of PhantomJS and Selenium on my Ubuntu machine I am running below code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")
driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage').send_keys("realpython")
driver.find_element_by_id("search_button_homepage").click()
print driver.current_url
driver.quit()
```

On execution I am getting below error:

```
$ python duck.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "duck.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('search_form_input_homepage').send_keys("realpython")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 208, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 664, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Error Message => 'Unable to find element with id 'search_form_input_homepage''
 caused by Request => {"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"107","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:50789","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\": \"id\", \"sessionId\": \"26560250-fec9-11e4-b2ee-2dada5838664\", \"value\": \"search_form_input_homepage\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/26560250-fec9-11e4-b2ee-2dada5838664/element"}
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting [`--ssl-protocol=any` service argument](http://www.markbetz.net/2014/11/10/phantomjs-aboutblank-and-ssl-protocol/) and using [Explicit Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) made it work for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ssl-protocol=any'])

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://duckduckgo.com/")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "search_form_input_homepage")))
search.send_keys("realpython")
driver.find_element_by_id("search_button_homepage").click()

print driver.current_url
driver.quit()
```

Prints `https://duckduckgo.com/?q=realpython`.

Note that without `--ssl-protocol=any` PhantomJS hasn't even loaded the page and the current url stayed as `about:blank`.

Answer (score 0):

I think whats happening to you is that you try to find an element which is not loaded yet on the page. So what I can recommend is the insert a `WaitForElementDisplayed(by.ID("search_form_input_homepage"));` right before you try to type in the search field. So you will be sure that the element is there before trying to interact with it.

I can't really give you a code example because I'm not really familiar with the Python bindings.

Comment: well what the exception says is either element is not there or we're using wrong identifier to find it. Now, assuming our identifier is correct, it leaves is with the other option that the element is not there yet. 
Just for the try can you insert a Thread.Sleep(5000) when the page is loaded and before trying to type. This will wait for 5 seconds before next interaction.

Comment: No, the problem is that the page is not even loading in PhantomJS.